# task<...> construction vs create_task

Tags: visual-c++, asynchronous, windows-runtime

According to [Asynchronous programming in C++ (Windows Store apps)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/hh780559.aspx):

```
// Explicit construction. (Not recommended)
// Pass the IAsyncOperation to a task constructor.
// task<DeviceInformationCollection^> deviceEnumTask(deviceOp);

// Recommended:
auto deviceEnumTask = create_task(deviceOp);
```

Why is assignment (`create_task`) preferred over construction?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you're just as bound either way.  You're bound to the class you're constructing as well as the factory interface you may be using and subject to maintaining compatibility with whatever changes are made to the public interfaces utilitized in your implementation.  Disruptive changes are just as possible in either location.  Microsoft's answer to this question comes from the create_task() documentation: create_task() is just a convenience function as it allows the use of the 'auto' keyword while creating tasks.  http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/hh913025.aspx

Answer (score 1):

I think the reason why using factories in general is more desirable rather than calling constructors is that this is less coupled with specific implementation of the interface. If you call constructor then your program is tightly coupled with given implementation.

Object construction with factories is less coupled, and also more flexible and extendable. For example, in the next version of the API providers might decide to deprecate certain implementation or replace it with something else. If you use only factory then they can simply change it's implementation to return instance of another class, or inject some more dependencies internally. But if your program is bound with specific class it would be much diffucult to achieve.